# Retrieve commit ids after/since a specific commit id

Tags: git

I am trying to get the list of all commit ids after/since a certain commit id, is there a git command..?

git log --pretty=format:"%H" --since=2014-05-04 would print all the commit-ids since 2014-05-04, similarly is there a command that could print all the commit ids after a certain commit-id?

Example:

123456daskkl9

56787skjskdk8

adkasjdka6788

dkajsdklja76678

jkajskldal677889

If I try "git log --pretty=format:"%H" adkasjdka6788"

The out put is

adkasjdka6788

dkajsdklja76678

jkajskldal677889

Instead, what I am looking for is a command that would get the below output

123456daskkl9

56787skjskdk8

Comment: It's the very first option listed in [the man-page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the commit range with the `<since>..<until>` syntax. If `until` is omitted, it will default to `HEAD`.

So, to get all the commits from hash `adkasjdka6788` to the current `HEAD` of the branch you're on:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" adkasjdka6788..
```